# Load data from CSV inside bit field in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, sql-insert

What's the right syntax to insert a value inside a column of type `bit(1)` in `MySQL'?

My column definition is:

```
payed bit(1) NOT NULL
```

I'm loading the data from a `csv` where the data is saved as `0` or `1`.
I've tried to do the insert using:

```
b'value' or 0bvalue (example b'1' or 0b1)
```

As indicated from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html).

But I keep getting this error:

```
 Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'payed' at row 1
```

What's the right way to insert a `bit` value?

I'm not doing the insert manually but I'm loading the data from a `csv` (using `load data infile`) in which the data for the column is `0` or `1`.

This is my `load` query, I've renamed the fields for privacy questions, there's no error in that definition:

```
load data local infile 'input_data.csv' into table table
fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
(id, year, field1, @date2, @date1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, payed, field8, field9,   field10, field11, project_id)
set
date1 = str_to_date(@date1, '%a %b %d %x:%x:%x UTC %Y'),
date2 = str_to_date(@date2, '%a %b %d %x:%x:%x UTC %Y');
show warnings;
```

This is an example row of my CSV:

```
    200014,2013,0.0,Wed Feb 09 00:00:00 UTC 2014,Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 UTC 2013,2500.0,21,Business,0,,0,40.0,0,PROSPECT,1,200013
```

**Update:**
I didn't find a solution with the `bit`, so I've changed the column data type from `bit` to `tinyint` to make it work.

Comment: Did you try to insert 0 or 1 ? Personnaly, i use `smallint(1) unsigned` to store boolean values.

Comment: can you show your insert statment ?

Comment: @echo_me: I'm not doing the insert manually, I'm loading the data from a CSV in which the data is saved as 0 or 1

Comment: Pls show your LOAD query and example rows from CSV.

Comment: I've added the load query and and excerpt from my CSV. Is not very readable but the problem is inserting the 0 or 1 values from the csv in the bit(1) column.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've finally found the solution and I'm posting it here for future reference. I've found help in the [mysql load data manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

So for test purpose my table structure is:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| nome   | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| valore | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My `csv` test file is:

```
1,primo_valore,1
2,secondo_valore,0
3,terzo_valore,1
```

The query to load the `csv` into the table is:

```
 load data infile 'test.csv' into table test
    fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
    (id, nome, @valore) set
       valore=cast(@valore as signed);
    show warnings;
```

As you can see do load the `csv` you need to do a cast `cast(@valore as signed)` and in your `csv` you can use the integer notation `1` or `0` to indicate the `bit` value. This is because BIT values cannot be loaded using binary notation (for example, `b'011010'`).

Answer (score 15):

Replace the "0" values in the csv by no value at all. That worked for me.

Comment: After some experimenting with the same problem it looks like for the bit field the value from the text file is interpreted as "whether there is a value (1) or there isn't (0)". Any value such as 0,1,2134,'True', 'foo', 'bla' is interpreted as (1)

Comment: thanks, this is the correct answer especially if your load command is generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BIN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_bin) function like this :

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (`column` = BIN(1)), (`column` = BIN(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, but I think you should ignore 1st line of your CSV file in LOAD query.

See "IGNORE number LINES"

Comment: Thanks, but I'm deleting the first line of the CSV