# MySQL Workbench, importing boolean fail. 1406 Data too long for column

Tags: mysql

Importing CSV file, I have tried switching SQL mode to not use STRICT. Also tried '1', 1, true and b'1' values with no success. Always 1406 error. What should I change?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TB1
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ENABLED BIT(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FEATURES PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Enabled is the field I have issue with

I am using import withard icon when you put mouse pointer over table name, and then "import records from external file"

CSV file:

```
ID;NAME;ENABLED
244;Test;b'1'
```

Comment: Please add table definition and sample csv file and explain what you mean by import - are you using an import wizard in workbench?

Comment: I assume that the comma at the end of ENABLED BIT(1) NOT NULL, is a typo? Also an auto_increment colimn must be defined as the primary key.AND there is an empty row in the csv file after the title row.

Comment: Yes you are right. They were typos

Comment: This is the closest answer I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683809/load-data-from-csv-inside-bit-field-in-mysql, together with the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), it leads to `load data infile 'test.csv' into table tb1  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (ID,NAME,@enabled) set enabled=CAST(CONV(MID(@enabled, 3, LENGTH(@enabled)-3), 2, 10) AS UNSIGNED);`

Comment: Thank you Luuk. I have seen there is no way to use wizard for BIT type. I am using Workbench 8.0.22